# How can I achieve the property swipe right and swipe left in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am seeking for whenever a user swipes right, then it would be gone on other page and in the same page if I again the swipe left it would be return me on a home page (from where I started to swipe right).

For a proper idea I am asking about like Instagram whenever I swipe right it will goes to you message section and in the same page if swipe left it will be return me on the main screen

Comment: Try out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050463/how-to-detect-swipe-in-flutter

Comment: And this one also https://pub.dev/packages/swipedetector

Comment: @AR sir in swipe dector i can go to the swipe right but we can not go to the home screen by using swipe left

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 ways that I can think of to do that:

1.The first and easier way is to use a `PageView`:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: [
          FirstPage(),
          SecondPage(),
          ThirdPage(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. The second way is to use a `TabBarView`:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: TabController(length: 3, vsync: this),
        children: [
          FirstPage(),
          SecondPage(),
          ThirdPage(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you have a tab bar use `TabBarView` otherwise `PageView` is better in every other way.

Comment: sir in pagevie we can only perform one action at a time and i havn`t use tabbarview

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean “only one action at a time”? How many actions are you trying to accomplish at one time?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gestures widget](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures#adding-gesture-detection-to-widgets). Look at ‘onHorizontalDrag’