# onVerticalDragUpdate calling multiple time in Flutter GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code, the `onVerticalDragUpdate`  called multiple times on swipe down/up. I tried to adjust sensitivity from zero. that not worked for me.

```dart
GestureDetector(
       onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
          if (details.delta.dy > 0) {
              print('------Down Swipe----');
                 changePage(currentPage++);
             }
       }
)
```

Also, I tried `onPanUpdate` which has the same problem.

```dart
GestureDetector(onPanUpdate: (details) {
   if (details.delta.dy > 0) {
    // swiping
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be a little late on this one but I went through the same issue and found the solution.

You need to combine

- `onPanUpdate` to get the direction and set a variable
- `onPanEnd` to set the state only when the move is finished

Example :

```
return GestureDetector(
  onPanEnd: (details) {
    if (direction == 'right') {
      activeIndex = (activeIndex! + 1);
      setState(() {});
    }
    if (direction == 'left') {
      activeIndex = (activeIndex! - 1);
      setState(() {});
    } else {}
  },
  onPanUpdate: (details) {
    // Swiping in right direction.
    if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
      direction = 'right';
    }

    // Swiping in left direction.
    if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
      direction = 'left';
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(...
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the point of this function. Based on the documentation:

> A pointer that is in contact with the screen with a primary button and
> moving vertically has moved in the vertical direction.

Meaning, this function would be called every time the vertical position changes on drag.

If you want to execute the function only once, use `onVerticalDragStart` or `onVerticalDragEnd` (based on what you want to achieve).

Comment: How can I achieve vertical swipe up/down? The function inside need not call multiple time.

Comment: Did you check for answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050463/how-to-detect-swipe-in-flutter)?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is the function inside calling multiple times.

Comment: Maybe you can improve the function, like having a flag that would change false/true when function is executed once?