# Can you make showSearch() Dismissible?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to make the [search dialog (`showSearch()`)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showSearch.html) `Dismissible`? I'd like to be able to swipe away the search page to close it.

Comment: Can you share some examples or something for more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050804/12059260

He wrote code for detecting swiping left or right. Write navigation.pop() on which swipe u wanna close search page, with animation u can make it smoother

Comment: How? `showSearch()` doesn't expose a `Widget` that we can pass as a `child`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use swipedetector as a parent for the search page and use the function onSwipeLeft or onSwipeRight to close the page calling pop function
https://pub.dev/documentation/swipedetector/latest/

There ya go

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> list = List.generate(10, (index) => "Text $index");

  MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Search Bar'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showSearch(context: context, delegate: Search(widget.list));
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: widget.list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Text(
            widget.list[index],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Search extends SearchDelegate {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.close),
        onPressed: () {
          query = "";
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }

  String selectedResult = "";

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(selectedResult),
      ),
    );
  }

  final List<String> listExample;
  Search(this.listExample);

  List<String> recentList = ["Text 4", "Text 3"];

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> suggestionList = [];
    query.isEmpty
        ? suggestionList = recentList //In the true case
        : suggestionList.addAll(listExample.where(
            // In the false case
            (element) => element.contains(query),
          ));

    return GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        // Swiping in right direction.
        if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
          print('right');
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }

        // Swiping in left direction.
        if (details.delta.dx < 0) {
          print('left');
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: suggestionList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                suggestionList[index],
              ),
              leading: query.isEmpty ? Icon(Icons.access_time) : SizedBox(),
              onTap: () {
                selectedResult = suggestionList[index];
                showResults(context);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Home]

[image]

With that code you could drag from anywhere in the body

Comment: How? `showSearch()` doesn't expose a `Widget` that we can pass as a `child`.