# How can I use navigation with bottom navigation bar -Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to use iOS style navigation in my flutter app and I tried many things but nothing worked so I decided to use page view to manage screens but I know that's not the proper method to manage routes so I just want to know how I can use navigation with bottom navigation bar in flutter.

Here is my source code:-
https://github.com/dipak1267/BottombaNavigationFlutter.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `GestureDetector.onPanUpdate` to detect a swipe like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55050804/11465355
2. Use `Navigator.pop(context)` in order to navigate back once you detected the swipe

Comment: I use getX so i  use Get.back instead of Navigator.pop(context)

Comment: Well, you said in the title "without lib" so I showed you how to do it without lib.

Comment: @DipakRamoliya feel free to accept this answer as the correct one if it solved your problem.

Comment: after many try it works thanks @heikkisorsa